# Como percorrer uma propriedade do tipo TObjectList via Rtti?

Tags: delphi, rtti

minha classe possui uma propriedade do tipo TObjectList:

```
TBaseModelo = class(TInterfacedPersistent)
public
    property ListaCamposValidacao: TObjectList<TCampoValidacao> read FListaCamposValidacao write FListaCamposValidacao;
end;
```

Preciso, através de RTTI, selecionar essa propriedade "ListaCamposValidacao" e percorrer ela para fazer uma ação, porém não faço muita ideia de como fazer.

```
Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
try
  Typ := Ctx.GetType(Objeto.ClassType);      
  ????? 
  //Typ.GetProperty('ListaCamposValidacao').GetValue(Objeto);
finally
  Ctx.Free;
end;
```

Alguém pode me ajudar, orientar em como implementar o código?

Comment: Podes colocar mais informações sobre como quer acessar a property? Já sabe o nome da property de antemão ou vai ter de encontrar o nome da property por RTTI tb?

Answer (score 1):

Segue um simples exemplo de como percorrer uma propriedade do tipo `TObjectList<T>`, sem dúvida existem outras inúmeras maneiras de se realizar esta tarefa, como o objetivo aqui é mostrar o caminho e a simplicidade esta é a melhor opção. Este exemplo não está validando propriedades ou seja sem métodos de acesso `getters&setters` está escrevendo e lendo tudo direto das variáveis de instância `campos/atributos da classe`

```
unit FrmPrincipal;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Generics.Collections, System.Rtti;

type

   TCampoValidacao = class
    private
      FId: string;
      FNome: string;
      FEndereco: string;
      FBairro: string;
    public
      property Id: string read FId write FId;
      property Nome: string read FNome write FNome;
      property Endereco: string read FEndereco write FEndereco;
      property Bairro: string read FBairro write FBairro;
   end;

   TBaseModelo = class(TInterfacedObject)
  private
    FListaCamposValidacao: TObjectList<TCampoValidacao>;
  public
      property ListaCamposValidacao: TObjectList<TCampoValidacao> read FListaCamposValidacao write FListaCamposValidacao;
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TModeloX = Class(TBaseModelo )
    private
    FId:string;
    FNome: string;
    FEndereco: string;
    FBairro: string;
    public
      property Id: string read FId write FId;
      property Nome: string read FNome write FNome;
      property Endereco: string read FEndereco write FEndereco;
      property Bairro: string read FBairro write FBairro;
  End;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btGerar: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure btGerarClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btGerarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    id: TGuid;
    meuModelo:  TModeloX;
    campoValidacao: TCampoValidacao;
    ctxRtti  : TRttiContext;
    typeRtti : TRttiType;
    propRtti : TRttiProperty;
    I: Integer;
begin
   meuModelo := TModeloX.Create;
   for I := 0 to 50 do
   begin
     CreateGUID(id);
     campoValidacao := TCampoValidacao.Create;
     campoValidacao.Id := System.SysUtils.GUIDToString( id );
     campoValidacao.Nome := 'MAURO' + IntToStr( i );
     campoValidacao.Endereco := 'RUA PEDRO PEREIRA - Nº ' + IntToStr( i );
     campoValidacao.Bairro := 'Vila Martins ';
     meuModelo.ListaCamposValidacao.Add(campoValidacao);
   end;
   campoValidacao := nil;

   ctxRtti  := TRttiContext.Create;

   for campoValidacao in meuModelo.ListaCamposValidacao do
   begin
     typeRtti := ctxRtti.GetType( campoValidacao.ClassType );
     for propRtti in typeRtti.GetProperties do
       Memo1.Lines.Add( propRtti.Name+': ' +  propRtti.GetValue( campoValidacao).ToString );
   end;
  ctxRtti.Free;
end;

{ TBaseModelo }

constructor TBaseModelo.Create;
begin
  FListaCamposValidacao := TObjectList<TCampoValidacao>.Create;
end;

destructor TBaseModelo.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned( FListaCamposValidacao ) then
    FListaCamposValidacao.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Fonte de pesquisa: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41728